# There is no "Generate Signed Bundle" menu optin in my android studio

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I would like to try Android's [App Bundle feature.](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/build)

However, when I would like to make my own app bundle, I cannot because t**here is no such menu option in my Android Studio**, see pic below.

[image]

The [official youtube video about this topic](https://youtu.be/9D63S4ZRBls?t=1m6s) shows the following:

[image]

I have also added `android.enableAapt2=true` to my `gradle.properties` file, just as the official sources say, also restarted Gradle daemon, also restarted Android Studio:

> Note: Android Studio requires AAPT2 to build app bundles, which is
>   enabled for new projects by default. However, to make sure it is
>   enabled on existing projects, include android.enableAapt2=true in your
>   gradle.properties file and restart the Gradle daemon by running
>   ./gradlew --stop from the command line.

What am I doing wrong?

**Where is the missing menu option?**

Comment: Download AS 3.2 Beta

Comment: Why do you need a bundle/apk there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is currently available in the canary and beta channels, but not the stable channel. Try downloading the best version.

Answer (score 1):

go to this location in Android studio
File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Facets

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the preview version of Android Studio (v3.2)
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/

After install this version, open your project and will appear a prompt to update the version of gradle.